# How to fix: Django forms: {{ form }} doesn't show up any result in html page

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4, django-forms

I've created a django form:

```
#forms.py
from django import forms


class NameForm(forms.Form):
subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
sender = forms.EmailField()
cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

and in view file:

```
#views.py
def get_form(request):
print(request.POST)
form = NameForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    print(form.cleaned_data)
return render(request, "name.html", {"title": "Contact us"})
```

I've imported to a html file inside templates folder:

```
#templates/name.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, it doesn't show up any thing just a submit button. I have no idea what is the issue. I'll be so grateful for a solution around this issue.

Update: If I create a new html file, the form is shown there. However, if I use it in my main html including boostarp, it is not showing up. Here is the full code of my html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- Team -->
    {% for card in cards %}
        <!-- Team member -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="image-flip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="mainflip">
                    <div class="frontside">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <p><img class=" img-fluid"
                                        src="https://sunlimetech.com/portfolio/boot4menu/assets/imgs/team/img_01.png"
                                        alt="card image"></p>
                                <h4 class="card-title">{{ card.name }}</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">{{ card.description }}</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="backside">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body text-center mt-4">
                                <h4 class="card-title">{{ card.name }}</h4>
                                <!--<p class="card-text"> {{ card.back_description }}-->
                                <form action="/your-name/" method="post">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {{ form }}
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                </form>
                                <!--</p> -->
                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-skype"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./Team member -->
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

It made me crazy for three days. I look forward for a solution. Thanks

Update2:

```
#base.html
{%  load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="{% static 'css/stylesheet.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="team" class="pb-5">
    <div class="container">
        <h5 class="section-title h1">OUR TEAM</h5>
        <div class="row">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>

#card.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- Team -->
    {% for card in cards %}
        <!-- Team member -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="image-flip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="mainflip">
                    <div class="frontside">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <p><img class=" img-fluid"
                                        src="https://sunlimetech.com/portfolio/boot4menu/assets/imgs/team/img_01.png"
                                        alt="card image"></p>
                                <h4 class="card-title">{{ card.name }}</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">{{ card.description }}</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="backside">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body text-center mt-4">
                                <h4 class="card-title">{{ card.name }}</h4>
                                <!--<p class="card-text"> {{ card.back_description }}-->
                                <form action="/your-name/" method="post">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {{ form }}
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                </form>
                                <!--</p> -->
                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-skype"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./Team member -->
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line on your **views.py** file:

```
return render(request, "name.html", {"title": "Contact us"})
```

into this one:

```
return render(request, "name.html", {'form': form })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This solved the issue. However, I've updated my question. Would you please check if there is solution for it, too ?

Comment: I have created boostrap cards and {{ form }} is not showing up in there.

Comment: after rendering form like I told still your form is not showing up? i didn't get your question after you've updated

Comment: I've created a base.html as a default html. I've created another html file named form.html and extends it from base.html. I also created another html named name.html which is an independent html. The form is working in Name.html but it is not working in form.html

Comment: the html code you've provided after updating, is that `form.html` code?

Comment: remove the  `{% for card in cards %}` and  `{% endfor %}` from the `form.html` then your form will be shown up